# Weird Issue in dotnet core website using MailKit to send email

Tags: smtp, .net-core, mailkit, .net-core-1.1

I just inherited a website from a vendor and going through the bugs and source code for the website.

The application is built on dotnet core 1.1 and uses Mailkit to send emails via SMTP thorugh our corporate proxy.

The issue is that the mail send feature behaves erratically in sending emails. Most of the times I debug the send method it errors out. We use the `Authentication` Required Flag and pass the userId and Password to MailKit `Authenticate` Method

StackTrace message

> AuthenticationInvalidCredentials: 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful
>
> at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.Authenticate(Encoding encoding,
>   ICredentials credentials, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MailKit.MailService.Authenticate(String userName, String password,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Rules.Emailer.SendNotification.Send(String to, String from, String
>   subject, String body) in
>   C:\Workspace\G\Rules\Emailer\SendNotification.cs:line
>   94    at G.Rules.Emailer.UserNotifications.ResetPassword(String

Code snippet

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    client.Connect(EmailConfiguration.SmtpServer, EmailConfiguration.SmtpPort, EmailConfiguration.UseSsl);

    if (EmailConfiguration.RequiresAuthentication)
    {
        client.Authenticate(EmailConfiguration.Username, EmailConfiguration.Password);
    }

    //TODO: Only Send if PROD
    client.Send(message);
    client.Disconnect(true);
}

return true;
}
```

Comment: Added the code which sends the email to SMTP using MailKit

Comment: I would recommend getting a protocol log to figure out why authentication is failing. See the FAQ for MailKit to learn how to do that.

Comment: added the protocol log

Comment: I use the corporate SMTP with System.Net.Mail just fine, below is an example
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient
                {
                    Host = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Host,
                    Port = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Port,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(mailSettings.Smtp.Network.UserName, mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Password),
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    //EnableSsl = true
                };

Comment: Where is the protocol log?

Comment: Added to the GitHub Bug page. https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/issues/686

Comment: Looks like you are sending a bad password which obviously won't work.

Comment: System.Net.Mail probably works because it is using NTLM authentication instead of LOGIN. You can specify using NTLM instead by calling `client.Authenticate (new SaslMechanismNtlm (credentials));`

Comment: I decoded the base64 pswd string , which is correct. i will try NTLM and confirm

Comment: Note: I have gotten mixed reports of MailKit's NTLM auth code working and for the reports saying it doesn't work, I've been unable to figure out why (which is why I removed it from the default list for MailKit to try).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To NTLM connection, you can try that:

```cs
await client.ConnectAsync(SmtpServer.SenderServer, SmtpServer.Port).ConfigureAwait(false);

if (client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Contains("NTLM"))
{
    var ntlm = new SaslMechanismNtlm(SmtpServer.UserName, SmtpServer.Password);
    await client.AuthenticateAsync(ntlm).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
else
{
    await client.AuthenticateAsync(SmtpServer.UserName, SmtpServer.Password).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Connected to smtp://<IP>:25/?starttls=when-available
S: 220 <Server_REDACTED>.<DOMAIN_REDACTED>.COM Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Tue, 27 Mar 2018 03:22:42 -0400
C: EHLO [10.207.8.74]
S: 250-<Server_REDACTED>.<DOMAIN_REDACTED>.COM Hello [10.207.8.74]
S: 250-SIZE
S: 250-PIPELINING
S: 250-DSN
S: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
S: 250-STARTTLS
S: 250-X-ANONYMOUSTLS
S: 250-AUTH NTLM
S: 250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250-BINARYMIME
S: 250-CHUNKING
S: 250-XEXCH50
S: 250-XRDST
S: 250 XSHADOW
C: STARTTLS
S: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
C: EHLO [10.207.8.74]
S: 250-<Server_REDACTED>.<DOMAIN_REDACTED>.COM Hello [10.207.8.74]
S: 250-SIZE
S: 250-PIPELINING
S: 250-DSN
S: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
S: 250-AUTH NTLM LOGIN
S: 250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250-BINARYMIME
S: 250-CHUNKING
S: 250-XEXCH50
S: 250-XRDST
S: 250 XSHADOW
C: AUTH LOGIN
S: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
C: <EMAIL_REDACTED>  
S: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
C: <PSWD_REDACTED> 
S: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful
```